# Click to edit tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

On math.stackexchange you can edit the tags by hovering to the right of the last tag.  A button labeled edit tags comes up.  I was asked to add a tag to a question I asked and this did not work.  I had to click the edit button and work on the post in the edit window.  I believe this site will require a lot of tag editing, so making it easy is a good idea.  Maybe it is because I don't have enough rep on this site yet.  Please institute the math.stackexchange behavior.

Answer (score 11):

This is a privilege unlocked at 10000 reputation for graduated sites (2000 in public beta, 1000 in private beta). It has absolutely nothing to do with math.SE or specific sites.

([Here have linky](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools))

Comment: He has more than 10.000 reputation on math.SE so that explains why he asks it.